# Placing graphs in a landscape grid (a python challenge)

Tags: python, gridview, matplotlib, charts, grid

I would like to place subplots in matplotlib so that I do not know how many graphs are there (variable number of graphs).

The grid dimensions is R * C so that R <= C, and the grid is filled fromleft to right and from top to bottom.

The challenge is that I want to make a function that returns a tuple of the location (r, c) for the chart number n

A sample diagram of the needed functions is shown below where group represents n(r,c) i.e. the number n should output the tuple(r,c)

```
sample
 0(0, 0)   1(0, 1)   4(0, 2)   9(0, 3)  16(0, 4)
 2(1, 0)   3(1, 1)   5(1, 2)  10(1, 3)  17(1, 4)
 6(2, 0)   7(2, 1)   8(2, 2)  11(2, 3)  18(2, 4)
12(3, 0)  13(3, 1)  14(3, 2)  15(3, 3)  19(3, 4)
20(4, 0)  21(4, 1)  22(4, 2)  23(4, 3)  24(4, 4)
```

Comment: Limited to 24, this can be solved by placing a dictionary like: '{0: (0, 0), 1: (0, 1), 4: (0, 2), 9: (0, 3), 16: (0, 4),  2: (1, 0), 3: (1, 1), 5: (1, 2), 10: (1, 3), 17: (1, 4),  6: (2, 0), 7: (2, 1), 8: (2, 2), 11: (2, 3), 18: (2, 4), 
12: (3, 0), 13: (3, 1), 14: (3, 2), 15: (3, 3), 19: (3, 4), 20: (4, 0), 21: (4, 1), 22: (4, 2), 23: (4, 3), 24: (4, 4)}'
but I want to generalize this function if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 0
y = 0
print (x,y)
for i in range(1,5):
    y = i
    print [(x,y) for x in range(i)]
    x = i  
    print [(x,y) for y in range(i+1)]
```

To add the numbers:

```
tuples=[]

x = 0
y = 0
n = 0
tuples.append((n,(x,y)))
for i in range(1,5):
    y = i
    for x in range(i):
        n+=1
        tuples.append((n,(x,y)))
    x = i  
    for y in range(i+1):
        n+=1
        tuples.append((n,(x,y)))

print tuples
```

Comment: Good job @Peter9192.
Thanks, I hope I could vote up, but my reputation is still low.